# MySQL query with multiple joins and compound select

Tags: mysql

I am almost there but not quite returning the results I need.

I have 3 tables. program_location, hcp_data, guest_data, all with proper primary keys.

Each row in hcp_data includes a reference (by foreign key) to 1 program location. Each row in guest_data includes a reference to a row in hcp_data. There may be multiple guests tied to one hcp_data entry. Think of these tables as party locations, invitees, and the people those invitees opt to bring with them to the same location, respectively. Thus via their relationships I can determine the location of a guest by the location of the hcp they are linked to.

So what I am trying to do is select all rows from hcp_data and additional_guest tables and join to each row a couple columns from the program_locations table. Essentially the purpose is dumping the data so that it makes sense as a single flat file.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT lname, fname, degree, email, job_title, office_addr_line_1, office_addr_line_2, hcp_data.city, hcp_data.state, hcp_data.zip, phone, timestamp, program_location.restaurant_name, program_location.city AS restaurant_city, program_location.state AS restaurant_state
FROM hcp_data 
LEFT JOIN program_location
ON hcp_data.program_location_idprogram_location = program_location.idprogram_location
UNION 
SELECT lname, fname, degree, email, job_title, office_addr_line_1, office_addr_line_2, additional_guest.city, additional_guest.state, additional_guest.zip, phone, timestamp, program_location.restaurant_name, program_location.city AS restaurant_city, program_location.state AS restaurant_state
FROM additional_guest
LEFT JOIN program_location
ON
```

The last ON is blank at the moment. I believe this is where I am stuck. I think I will need to do a composite select for one of the sides but I am not sure.

Please help! thanks!

Edit,BTW, the primary keys for each table are simply the table name with "id" appended up front, i.e. "idprogram_location"
Foreign keys are the table which they come from, underscore, the name of the column in the table they come from: i.e. "program_location_idprogram_location"

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out. If there is an easier or better way (which I don't doubt there is) please share!

```
SELECT lname, fname, degree, email, job_title, office_addr_line_1, office_addr_line_2, hcp_data.city, hcp_data.state, hcp_data.zip, phone, timestamp, program_location.restaurant_name, program_location.city AS restaurant_city, program_location.state AS restaurant_state
FROM hcp_data 
LEFT JOIN program_location
ON program_location.idprogram_location = hcp_data.program_location_idprogram_location
UNION 
SELECT lname, fname, degree, email, job_title, office_addr_line_1, office_addr_line_2, additional_guest.city, additional_guest.state, additional_guest.zip, phone, timestamp, program_location.restaurant_name, program_location.city AS restaurant_city, program_location.state AS restaurant_state
FROM additional_guest
LEFT JOIN program_location
ON program_location.idprogram_location = 
(SELECT idprogram_location 
FROM program_location 
WHERE idprogram_location = 
(SELECT program_location_idprogram_location 
FROM hcp_data 
WHERE idhcp_data = 
(SELECT hcp_data_idhcp_data 
FROM additional_guest LIMIT 1)));
```